# Creating notifications on receive a call

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

I am creating an application and a certain part of my code I need to create a notification when I receive a call. The problem is that I am not able to implement the notification, since I have to pass the number of who is calling me. The following pieces of my code.

My Receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    CallIntercepterListener callIntercepterListener = new CallIntercepterListener();

    telephonyManager.listen(callIntercepterListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
    Log.d(TAG, "phoneNumber: " + phoneNumber);
}
```

and My Listener:

```
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Event Call: " + incomingNumber);

    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            // Create a notification with de incomingNumber
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do yo need the listener for? Your receiver gets already called whenever the phone state changes.

[here is a nice article about how to use the BroadcastReceiver.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

From this article:

```
package de.vogella.android.receiver.phone;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
      Log.w("DEBUG", state);
      if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        String phoneNumber = extras
            .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Log.w("DEBUG", phoneNumber);
      }
    }
  }
}
```